# Onboarding Server 2016 to Defender ATP Package Fails to Install

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-defender

I am having issues onboarding multiple Windows Server 2016 to Defender ATP.

The initial installation of the Onboarding Package fails and rolls back.

The server I am focusing on currently is fully updated and has Windows Defender Antivirus installed and updated.

I turned on logging for the MSI installation and it doesn't show much but these are the errors listed.

MSI (s) (A0:64) [12:12:44:131]: The call to SRSetRestorePoint API failed. Returned status: 0. GetLastError() returned: 127

CustomAction UninstallSecFilter returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)

CustomAction  returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)

CustomAction RollbackUninstallSecFilter returned actual error code 1603 but will be translated to success due to continue marking

If someone has experience with this issue or can point me in a direction of something to try I would really appreciate it.